# Make everything inside a div fix size

Tags: css

How to do resize everything inside a div tag taking its maximum size nwidth and height

My div is:

```
<div style="width: 300px; height:60px">dynamique content </div>
```

However, if I have pictures, images, if it is bigger than the div, the image is not resize to the div, instead the div is getting bigger.

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

With CSS you could do:

```
div * {
    max-width: 300px;
}
```

You can see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/aEJuq/

Comment: Hi, I tried out max-width, max-height, but doesn' t seems to work, the pictures doesn' t resize automatically

Comment: @dtjmsy you need to show us your code then, as it works fine in the example.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this by below method

```
id or class or name {
    max-width: 300px;
    max-height: 60px;
}
```

you can do  this for image  by either set the `max-height` and `max-width` in picture by either id or key or inline css or in the html img tag like `<img   src="image your"   width="your width" height="your height">`

Answer (score 1):

Use max-width and max-height

```
   #blockUI img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```